# how do I surf to a mycompany.local address from linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu-16.04

Relevant hardware:
Laptop with ethernet cable plugged in, dual boot win 10 and ubuntu 16.04

There's an url I need to be able to access that I assume points to a server on the local network. The url is like `tool.mycompany.local`. This url works on my windows boot but not on my linux boot (`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` in chrome).

The biggest issue is that I have no idea what to google (".local" searches for "local") and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local doesn't seem to have the info I need (or I don't understand it).

I've tried tracing the ip for that url from windows, which works, but if I try to access that ip from linux I get redirected to the url upon which I get the same ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED as I did before.

The servicedesk here is no help as everyone is expected to work with windows and I'm an external consultant with my own laptop.

Worst case I reboot to windows so it's not that big of an issue, I'd mostly want to know why this happens and whether I can fix this on my end.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm a retard and completely missed the second part of the redirect: it not only redirects to the url, but more specifically to a login page along the lines of `tool.mycompany.local/login`. replacing the base url with the ip address again shows me the login page again.

That aside, not having to manually replace that each time would be nice.

EDIT2:
Like I said in a comment: I tried with `wget` and `curl` too, and no difference. I've also tried with `nslookup` on linux and it DOES work!

Why don't chrome / wget / curl use that nameserver then?

EDIT3:
to answer a question from the comments:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: You need to use a DNS server that is able to resolve the address. Windows might be picking it up by using the DHCP configuration. For Linux I'm not sure what you might have to look into. The static configuration should be in `resolv.conf` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Could you add the content of your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file to your question? Particularly the line starting with `hosts:`?

Comment: @user2313067 done, but from the comments at the top of that file I get the feeling this isn't being used?

Comment: Try to remove `[NOT FOUND=return] ` from the hosts line.  I don't know why that comment is there but unless Ubuntu does strange patches to glibc, this should be used.

Comment: @user2313067 `.local` is often a poor choice for an intranet DNS: it should be reserved for multicast DNS (the mdns4_minimal entry). Depending on settings this can slow down or make DNS requests fail (notwithtanding a wrong DNS server), precisely because it's before "dns" in the lookup order, probably to implement rfc 6762 efficiently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS#Protocol_overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your Linux OS is not using the same DNS server as your Windows OS. So, first figure out what DNS server(s) your Windows install is using. To do this, open a command prompt and run the `ipconfig /all` and looks the DNS server(s). Take note of their IP addresses. Then in your Linux OS, edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and add the following lines to the top of the file:

```
nameserver dns.1.ip.addr
nameserver dns.2.ip.addr
```

Where you of course replace dns.1.ip.addr with their actual IP addresses.

Now your linux OS should use the same DNS servers. Note that this is really a temporary solution. In reality, you should configure your linux box to use DHCP to pull the DNS settings.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, I'll check that out when I boot to windows again, thanks!

Comment: wait, plot twist: nslookup works fine on linux too, why can't chrome/wget/curl find the right ip then?

Comment: See @user2313067 comment and mine after. If you're not using mdns at all, you should completely remove the mdns4_minimal entry in /etc/nsswitch.conf . That's because `.local` has been reserved for mdns (too bad if your intranet domain ending in `.local` existed before this RFC in standard track.).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try it with a command line tool like `wget` or `curl` instead of a full fledged web browser.

This sounds like a DNS problem to me.

What happens if you find out the IP address of that site on your Windows box, e.g. use

```
nslookup tool.mycompany.local
..
Adresses:  12.34.56.78
..
```

from a command line (e.g. `cmd.exe`) and then try to fetch the page with your browser or tool trough http://12.34.56.78/etc on the Linux box?

This would show if you are blocked by some firewall or not or whatever other network issue. And then you could continue to fix your DNS setup.

Comment: I did find the address with nslookup on windows; though I used chrome (see 4th paragraph), wget and curl get the same redirect. You did help me realize part of a workaround though, thanks!

Comment: The quickest hack is resolving that address by a line in your `/etc/hosts` file. If you want to configure your DNS some important files are `/etc/network/interfaces`, `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, you can consult your favourite search engine for more information on them, or old school, read their `man` pages.